# AppleScript find according to multiple critria

Tags: find, applescript, intersection

Endnote X9 stores references such that AppleScript can find a references by a variable:

```
find "Thesis" in field "Reference Type"
```

However, I should also like apply another criterion to this selection –

```
find "A notional thesis title" in field "Title"
```

How does one find the intersection between these two 'find conditions' – such that a reference is found with reference type being 'thesis' and title being 'A notional thesis title'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What AppleScript can do is heavily dependent on what scriptable apps are designed to allow. I don't have a copy of Endnote X9, but looking at the AppleScript reference in [their documentation](https://support.clarivate.com/Endnote/servlet/fileField?entityId=ka14N000000MrSMQA0&field=CA_Attachment_1__Body__s) (pp. 492-7), it seems as though their `find` command is designed to be limited to a single field. One can't do real database-type searches using it (pity; that is an easy enough implementation).

You might have more luck using the `perform query` command (at the end, under the heading 'technical scripting'), but it's not well documented. You may also be able to do something with groups (somehow set up one search as a temporary group and then do the second search within the group), but I can't really test any of this without the app.

Your best bet might be to go to [Endnote X9's support page](https://support.clarivate.com/Endnote/s/?language=en_US) and ask the devs there. They obviously have some AppleScript people there (which is rare enough), so they might have some insight. If they want to shoot me a test copy I'll look into it myself (and maybe give them some tips for sprucing up their AppleScript support), but otherwise... Good luck!